# Remove Points that Overlay

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I have a pointlayer and some points overlay and i want to remove them, so that only one point remains. the points that overlay have the same coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an ArcInfo license level use ArcGIS tool [Delete Identical (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000053000000). Use "Shape field" as field whose values will be compared to find identical records.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Collect Events tool in ArcGIS.

Not only will it combine all the points at a location to a single point, it will also give you a count of how many points were combined together at each location.

Documentation for the tool can be found at:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005p0000003s000000

Answer (score 0):

There is a software called [ET GeoWizards](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_main.htm) which is added as a toolbar to ArcGIS and is free to use for up to 100 features. The tool you are looking for is called Clean Points, which removes any duplicate layers.

Worth checking out as there a many useful tools that ESRI doesn't provide. And it's cheap as well - compared to an ArcInfo license!

Btw. I don't get anything for advertising, but it has saved me many days over the years and Ianko Tchoukanski is very good in coming back in case you have any queries.